# Improve cube processing using an index

Tags: sql-server, ssas, clustered-index

I have a large fact table (Lets just call it Groupings) that is being used for cube processing. Right now it has approx 850 million rows for 1 year of data and is still being loaded daily, with I think a minimum of 2 million rows per day.

This table has 20 columns, three of these columns are:

- GroupCategory varchar (100)
- GroupSubCategory nvarchar(100)
- Date int (which is also the Clustered Index that will be used for    cube partitioning).

I have several measuregroups which has a query below:

```
Select 
    GroupName
    , GroupCategory
    , ...
    , ...
from [Groupings] 
Where 
    GroupCategory = 'GroupCategory_1'
    AND Date >= AnIntDate
    AND Date <  AnIntDate
```

The only difference in the query for the other measuregroups is the `'GroupCategory_1'`, it could be `'GroupCategory_2'` or `'GroupCategory_3'` in other measuregroups.

We need to reduce the cube processing time, and these measuregroups are the bottlenecks. I have already tried making `GroupCategory` and `Date` as ClusteredIndex.

I think I am using the right index. I there anything I can check?

Comment: If you have a test environment, read up on index design and then try out a few different indexes.  You can force a query to use an index and run an estimated execution plan (or just run the query with the actual plan included) and determine which has the better performance.  Also read up on statistics if you are adding lots to the table frequently.

Comment: Are the 2 million rows a day inserts? Updates? Are they all for the most recent month? Are you partitioned in the cube? Are you partitioned in SQL? Are you processing all SSAS partitions daily currently?

Comment: We do not do updtes, what just do delete and insert for the current month or day. We dont have the cube/sql partitioned yet, but we are planning to. We are doing full processing of the cube daily.